# Is 'Desktop' the best term for a PC based on a 'table'?

Tags: terminology

Since ALL operating systems have a 'Desktop' - The area of the screen that contains your regularly used shortcuts, taskbar, menu and notification areas.

It would be more accurate to be 'Workstation' that shows a 'Desktop' for user interaction.

Equally, a 'Laptop' or 'Portable' that shows a 'Desktop' for user interaction.

... All PC's have a 'Desktop'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, JN. 'Best' is a nebulous descriptor. often (and certainly here) subjectively decided. When seeking better terminology in general, a more logical D-I-Y term that nobody uses would certainly not be 'best'. Here, 'workstation' has at least one sense other than 'a desk with a computer', and so is itself not ideal.

Comment: You seem to have confused a "desktop computer" and "the desktop on a computer" (Although I must admit that I don't recognise the latter term.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: A "workstation" is a (marketing rather than technical) term for a certain category of personal computers; I _suspect_ that's what's being referred to here, though it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Not all operating systems have a desktop, so there you go. The name _desktop computer_ refers to the location of the thing, just like _laptop computer_. It does not mean that it may show a desktop to the user.

Comment: A workstation is a computer for end-users, unlike a server. Desktops and laptops are both workstations. Even if the term "desktop" is also used to refer to the working area of the workstation screen, "desktop" is the appropriate word for computers designed to fit on top of a typical office desk.